# Setting private property in super Class from Child class

Tags: php, oop

I have the following classes

- **Abstract class duck**
  This class have `flyBehavoir` of type `FlyBehavoir`
  Function to perform flying `preformFly()`
  Function to set `flyBehavoir` `setFlyBrhavoir(FlyBehavoir $flyBehavoir)`
- **Class DonaldDuck extends Duck**
  in this class, I have a `__construct` method, inside this constructor, I instantiate new fly behavior `FlyWithWings`.

The problem is when I need to change `flyBehavoir` in the runtime via `setFlyBrhavoir()` method and set it to `FlyWithRocket` it does not change as long as `flyBehavoir` is private if I make it public it works fine. how can I do that?

thought that we can change any property in the superclass from the child class, as long as I access this private property vis setter.

below my attempt

```
 <?php

//abstract class that defines what it takes to be a duck
//inside Duck we will have $flyBehavoir object of FlyBehavoir Type 
abstract class Duck{
    private  $flyBehavoir; 

    public function preformFly(){
        $flyBehavoir.fly();
    }
    public function setFlyBehavoir(FlyBehavoir $flyBehavoir){
        $this->flyBehavoir =  $flyBehavoir;
    }
}

//creating type FlyBehavoir 
interface FlyBehavoir{
    function fly();
}

//this concrete class of type FlyBehavoir  this will provide our ducks with the functionality they need to fly
class FlyWithWings implements FlyBehavoir{
    public function fly(){
        echo "I am Flying with my own Wings<br>";
    }
}

//this concrete class of type FlyBehavoir  this will provide our ducks with the functionality they need to fly
class FlyWithRocket implements FlyBehavoir{
    public function fly(){
        echo "I am the fastest duck ever, see my rockets wings <br>";
    }
}


// creating our first duck and given it the ability to fly with wings
class DonaldDuck extends Duck{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->flyBehavoir =  new FlyWithWings;
    }

}


$donaldDuck = new DonaldDuck( ) ;

$donaldDuck->flyBehavoir->fly();
//changing behavoir in run time 
$donaldDuck->setFlyBehavoir(new FlyWithRocket);
$donaldDuck->flyBehavoir->fly();


Output
I am Flying with my own Wings
I am Flying with my own Wings
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the problem, you have already mentioned the solution in your question: You need to use the setter instead of accessing the property directly.

Comment: That is what `private` means… You want `protected` instead.

Comment: use public/protected instead of private.

Comment: jeroen i am using setter if you check the code,

Comment: deceze  protected  give another error ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property DonaldDuck::$flyBehavoir in /home/yazfarqj/dev/headFirstDesignPatrenBook/ch1/duck3.php on line 48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `private` property is not accessible in child classes.

```
class DonaldDuck extends Duck {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->flyBehavoir = new FlyWithWings;
    }
}
```

For all intents and purposes, this class does not formally declare `flyBehaviour` at all, so `$this->flyBehaviour` in the constructor creates a new *`public`* property. You can see that clearly when `var_dump`ing the object:

```
object(DonaldDuck)#1 (2) {
  ["flyBehavoir":"Duck":private]=>
  NULL
  ["flyBehavoir"]=>
  object(FlyWithWings)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

The parent's `private` property is a) separate, b) `private` to it and c) `null` since nobody has set it yet. Otherwise it would also not be possible for you to access `$donaldDuck->flyBehavoir->fly()` from without the class!

If you have a `private` property, you need to only let code of the same class act on it:

```
class DonaldDuck extends Duck {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->setFlyBehaviour(new FlyWithWings);
    }
}

$donaldDuck = new DonaldDuck();
$donaldDuck->setFlyBehavoir(new FlyWithRocket);
$donaldDuck->preformFly();
```

This works as you expect, since you're using the correctly privileged methods to access the property. If you want to access the property directly in child classes, it needs to be `protected` (which then won't let you access it from outside the class though, it would have to be `public` for that).

Comment: Amazing clear explanation sir thank you very its clear now like crystal.